# what's the meaning of Requested resource=<memory:-1, vCores:1> in hadoop web ui?

Tags: hadoop

I want to insert some data in to hive table.
but it is stuck.

So I go to the hadoop web ui and find the following information:

org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: 
Invalid resource request, requested resource type=[memory-mb] < 0 or greater than maximum allowed allocation.
 Requested resource=<memory:-1, vCores:1>, maximum allowed allocation=<memory:4096, vCores:2>,
 please note that maximum allowed allocation is calculated by scheduler based on maximum resource of registered NodeManagers, which might be less than configured maximum allocation=<memory:9216, vCores:4>

My question:
what's the meaning of Requested resource=`<memory:-1, vCores:1>` in hadoop web ui?

I mean:
`memory:-1`
what's this?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it,it's caused by tez.
The solution is [here](https://yuchi.blog.csdn.net/article/details/111388141)